# what tools are available to analyze mobile site performance?

Tags: performance, mobile

the tool must:
1) Test the page/component load/render time.
2) Be usable on multiple devices/browsers.
3) Show results with recommendations per-device/browser

Comment: In lieu of a tool - the best article for mobile tools IMHO would be http://mashable.com/2010/07/13/mobile-web-optimization/

Answer (score 3):

The following tools may not meet all your requirements but you can check them out -

- [mobiReady](http://mobiready.com/)
- [MITE](http://mite.keynote.com/)
- [IBM Rational Performance Tester](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/07/1106_dash-kapasi/)

For some general recommendations, check the [slides of the Mobile Web High Performance presentation](http://en.oreilly.com/velocity2010/public/schedule/detail/13063) at the Velocity 2010 conference

Comment: thanks but I would prefer to get the data from a real device and not an emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a presentation on "[mobile web high performance](http://www.slideshare.net/firt/mobile-web-high-performance)".

Also, check out this question: [How can I simulate mobile device browsers to test websites on a desktop?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1248/tools-to-simulate-mobile-devices-on-a-desktop-to-test-websites)