# How can I simulate mobile device browsers to test websites on a desktop?

Tags: mobile, tools, browsers

Are there any good tools that can be run on desktop machines (Windows or Linux) that can simulate a mobile device, preferably with some options as to screen size and mobile browser (user agent if not full render engine).

I know it is never going to be perfect (especially without an actual touchscreen), but having a tool on our development machines to do what testing we can that way would be very useful.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464089/simulators-emulators-for-mobile-browser-testing

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a round-up of them on [Mashable](http://mashable.com/2010/07/13/mobile-web-optimization/) (second section).

> [iBBDemo2](http://www.puresimstudios.com/ibbdemo/) — This Adobe Air app will let you see content as it would appear on the iPad and on the iPhone. Support for Android is reportedly coming soon. The app is a bit slow but it does a good job showing accurate results for iOS devices. Just point the app towards your test mobile site.
>
> [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) — The Android SDK comes with its own device emulator so you can see how websites will appear on Android handsets. Check out these guides for installing the Android SDK on [Mac](http://www.buildcontext.com/blog/2009/11/06/installing-android-sdk-browser-testing-mac-os-x/) or [Windows](http://www.maggadget.com/try-android-2-1-on-windows/).
>
> [Blackberry Web Development Page](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/browserdev/) — This page gives you access to the BlackBerry simulators and includes tips for designing for BlackBerry devices.
>
> [Symbian S60 SDKs](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Library/Tools_and_downloads/Other/Symbian_SDKs/) — Nokia’s site has information on the S60 platform and available emulators.
>
> [Opera Mini Emulator](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-mobile-10-widgets-mobile-emulator-desktop/) — Opera has a desktop version of its mobile browser and lots of resources about designing for Opera Mobile across platforms.

Also using [Virtual PC 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=04d26402-3199-48a3-afa2-2dc0b40a73b6&displaylang=en) you can install a [Windows Mobile Emulator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=1a7a6b52-f89e-4354-84ce-5d19c204498a&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 5):

You can use Safari with select menu : Develope -> User Agents -> Iphone/iPod/ iPad  to Simulate testing in iPhone/ iPod/ iPad device.

In Firefox, you can add plugin FireMobileSimulator to simulate testing in some specific Japan mobile (Docomo, Softbank, ...)

Comment: As per Safari, Chrome has this feature too. Open developer tools, then press the cog - bottom-right corner. It has options for a variety of user agents and resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

The [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/) comes with an emulator that you could use to test your websites.

Comment: @ChrisF: fixed!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the iPhone simulator (iOS Simulator) that comes with the iPhone developer kit.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://quirktools.com/screenfly/. It lets you choose screen size and mimics the user agent string.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can add to the list of tools - Mobile Opera browser emulator http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/mobile/

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

There are some solutions that allow you to remotely test on real devices.

Free solutions

- [Nokia Remote Device Access](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Devices/Remote_device_access/)
- [Samsung's Test lab.dev](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/bbs/lab/view.do?platformId=2)

Commercial solutions

- [DeviceAnyWhere](http://www.deviceanywhere.com)
- [Perfecto Mobile](http://www.perfectomobile.com)

Comment: You may also like Adobe Shadow - http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/shadow/ and MobilePerf http://stevesouders.com/mobileperf/

Answer (score 0):

Chrome's "[Device Mode Mobile Emulation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode#enable-device-mode)" lets you test across a variety of user agents and resolutions.